# Sum of series using method of differences

Tags: summation, summation-method

How do I show that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+2}\right)
=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}.$$
using the method of differences?

Comment: Learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for posting here. Also share your thoughts/attempts on the problem; this isn't a homework site.

Comment: sorry i'm new to this site. This isn't my "homework" - I am genuinely trying to understand the question.

Comment: Don't have to be sorry. It's just that a bit of context adds clarity to your posts.

Comment: I see, I will have a look - thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that there is a typo in the formula. It should be
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{2}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+2}\right)
=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}.$$

I do not know what you mean by "method of differences".
Anyway you can show the identity in the following way.

Let $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$. Then 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{2}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+2}\right)=
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k+2}\\
=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-2\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k}+
\sum_{k=3}^{n+2}\frac{1}{k}\\
=H_n-2\left(H_n-1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)+\left(H_n-1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}\right)\\
=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}.$$

Comment: Ahh my problem is that I don't understand how you got to the last part of your hint. How comes you removed what you had just put up? I get how you've separated the sum but what is the Hn-2?

Comment: @MATHSHELPNEEDED Note that $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k+1}=\frac{1}{2}+\dots +\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}=H_n-1+\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: @MATHSHELPNEEDED Any further doubt?

Comment: Yes, where does the -1 come from in the Hn-1?

Comment: @MATHSHELPNEEDED Because $H_n$ starts from $1$. $H_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: 'method of differences' probably means a telescoping series here.

Comment: Also do you mind adding back the line where you made k=2 and k=3 in the sum?

Comment: So how did you even get to that line, where you get k=2 and k=3. That is where I'm confused.

Comment: @MATHSHELPNEEDED Try to expand $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k+1}$ and  $\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k}$. You will realize that they are summing the same set of numbers: $\frac{1}{2}+\dots +\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: oh wow, that makes sense now, thank you so much! so is there a general way I can apply this to other questions of this nature? Because I understand it in the context of this question but I feel like I might get lost again if it were a different question.

Comment: @MATHSHELPNEEDED Yes, changing the variables in a sum (like in integrals) can be useful in similar questions.